# PHP files not loading - empty source

Tags: php, ubuntu

My PHP files are not loading properly on my Ubuntu server.
Any PHP files including a simple "phptest.php" do not load.

The source of any PHP file is completely empty.

the error log says:

```
 PHP warning: Unknown: failed to open stream Permission denied in Unknown on line 

PHP Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'var/www/Site/public/phptest.php (include_path='.:/var/www/Site in Unknown on line 0
```

Does anyone have some ideas?

Comment: As you see, there are permission issues. Check the peormission on that directory / file.

Comment: Include the code that you are using along with your system settings (directory structure and permissions)if possible

Comment: Try setting your permissions to 777 temporarily and see if that fixes the problem. Also, maybe you could supply a directory listing.

Comment: On terminal just execute the command `sudo chmod -R 0777 /var/www/Site/.` and then it will work.

Comment: Just keep in mind, if the `chmod` to 777 works, you'll want more subtle settings afterwards! Setting access permissions to 777 is something you normally only do when debugging.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Indeed, you do not want files chmodded 777 in your production environment.

Comment: It has permission issues.. Just change the permissions and it'll be fine...